# Servlet which intercepts and redirects to another port

Tags: java, web-applications, servlets, port, servlet-filters

I have a machine which has two servers running: -

- A *Java web container* (`Weblogic`), and
- A *non-Java web server*

obviously on two different ports `7001` and `15000`.

The security policy restrictions on the server (and its network) only let us access to `Java web container` remotely (only its port is accessible).

I need a servlet or filter to be deployed on my Java web container which redirects certain requests to non-java web server and returns their result.

Is there any available `Servlet` or `filter` which does this?

I can upload files to *non-Java web application* (when accessed from the same machine). Is it possible to enable this feature by *Port Mapping Servlet*?

Comment: Do you have an HTTP server in your architecture, in front of the Weblogic server?

Comment: Nope, just direct access to Weblogic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no *standard* way to do this. In other words, there is nothing in the JavaEE spec to mandate containers to provide such functionality.

You'll have to write it on your own. I'd use a filter instead of a Servlet for that purpose.

Answer (score 1):

If only one server is publicly available a redirect won't help you since the browser won't have access to the port he gets redirected to. What you need in this case is a proxy in WebLogic. There is for example the [Jetty Proxy Servlet](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/Asynchronous+Proxy+Servlet) but I don't know how portable it is, also it probably requires servlet 3.0.

Answer (score 0):

You can't redirect, cause redirects are client-side, you need to make the simplest proxy. You can create a servlet accepting some param=web-url then you connect to this URL using URLConnection or commons http client then you just write the page you got into the servletResponse. Depending on the pages content you may also need to pass some http headers, but in the simplest case the schema is like I described